# Solved : ReactJS : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined when posting to a Laravel Controller using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, axios

I'm trying to get data and display it as a dynamic selection / option menu using ReactJs, and POST the chosen value to a Laravel controller, so I can't store it as well.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Sm extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            json:JSON.parse(props.data)
        };

        this.onChangeValue = this.onChangeValue.bind(this);
        this.onSubmitButton = this.onSubmitButton.bind(this);
    }

    onChangeValue(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onSubmitButton(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        axios.post('/Y', {
            name: this.state.json.id//error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // console.log(error);
            console.log(this.state.json.id);// error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
        });

        this.setState({
            name: ''
        })
    }

    componentDidMount () {
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitButton}>
                <select>
                    {this.state.json.map(i => (
                        <option className="form-control" name="name" value={i.id} onChange={this.onChangeValue}>{i.name}</option>//the id proprty is working :/
                    ))}
                </select>
                <button className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('sm')) {
    var data = document.getElementById(('sm')).getAttribute('data');
    ReactDOM.render(<Sm data={data}/>, document.getElementById('sm'));
}
```

everything works fine, but when I post the chosen value, I face this error: Uncaught TypeError: Unable to read the property 'id' of undefined, BUT on the other hand the property id is defined because its functioning I can see that in the `<option className="form-control" name="name" value={i.id} onChange={this.onChangeValue}>{i.name}</option>`

i even tried `this.state.json.i.id` and still the same problem.

-Update :My new code:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Sm extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            json:JSON.parse(props.data)
        };

        this.onChangeValue = this.onChangeValue.bind(this);
        this.onSubmitButton = this.onSubmitButton.bind(this);
    }

    onChangeValue(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onSubmitButton(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        axios.post('/Y', {
            name: this.state.name////500 (Internal Server Error)
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // console.log(error);
            console.log(this.state.name);//Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
            //console.log(this.state);//Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
            //console.log(this);//undefined
        });

        this.setState({
            name: ''
        })
    }

    componentDidMount () {
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitButton}>
                <select>
                    {this.state.json.map(i => (
                        <option className="form-control" name="name" value={i.id} onChange={this.onChangeValue}>{i.name}</option>//the id proprty is working :/
                    ))}
                </select>
                <button className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('sm')) {
    var data = document.getElementById(('sm')).getAttribute('data');
    ReactDOM.render(<Sm data={data}/>, document.getElementById('sm'));
}
```

the code final version :

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Sm extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            json:JSON.parse(props.data),
            name: ''
        };

        this.onChangeValue = this.onChangeValue.bind(this);
        this.onSubmitButton = this.onSubmitButton.bind(this);
    }

    onChangeValue(e) {
        this.setState({
            // [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            name: e.target.value
        });
        console.log("Am i working ?");
    }

    async onSubmitButton(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
        const response = await axios.post('/Y', {name: this.state.name});
        console.log(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(this.state.name);
        }

        this.setState(prevState => ({...prevState, name: ''}));
      }

    componentDidMount () {
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitButton}>
                <select onChange={this.onChangeValue} >
                    {this.state.json.map(i => (
                        <option className="form-control" name="name" value={i.id}>{i.name}</option>
                    ))}
                </select>
                <button className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('sm')) {
    var data = document.getElementById(('sm')).getAttribute('data');
    ReactDOM.render(<Sm data={data}/>, document.getElementById('sm'));
}
```

Comment: What is in `props.data`?

Comment: props.data is the data I get from the database using a laravel controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select something, **you store the id in `state.name`**, so the selected id is available here and should work.

`i.id` works because you are in a map. You won't be able to do json.id since json contains multiple sub objects.

So you axios request should looks like this :

```
axios.post('/Y', {name: this.state.name})
  .then(...)
```

**[Edit]**: Here is your onSubmit method as async :

```
async onSubmitButton(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/Y', {name: this.state.name});
    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(this.state.name);
  }

  this.setState(prevState => ({...prevState, name: ''}));
}
```

Comment: yeah youre right the `i.id` works just because it inside the map  , i changed this.state.json.id to  this.state.name and now im facing a new error that is :

`app.js:66227 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`

and while trying to see what happening i find this problems too
 

`console.log(this.state.name);//Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined


 //console.log(this.state);//Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined


//console.log(this);//undefined`

Comment: @YassineGhz Can you update your post with your new code please ?

Comment: yeah sure @Quentin Grisel , and thank you sooo much for your time.

Comment: i think that the problem now is the  `axios.post`

Comment: There seems to be 2 problems. 1- Your POST request is not working. I don't know how axios works but usually, `InternalServerError` means there is a problem in your backend. 2- http request are async so you should use async.await pattern. Else, the last setState could erase the value of state.name before the request is done.

Comment: yeah you are right the setState delete s evrything , axios wont post null variables. Should i delete the `this.setState{name: ' '}`

Comment: No don't worry, i edited my post so you can see how you can handle this case

Comment: yeah you are right , but it apears i allso have a problem in 

`onChangeValue(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    }`

and the proof is , if i initiase the name variable declared in from `  this.state = {
                json:JSON.parse(props.data),
                name: ''
            };` 
to   

`this.state = {
                json:JSON.parse(props.data),
                name: '123'
            };`

im my database i can see it stored

Comment: thank you brother soo much i finally fixed the last probleme ;it  was here :

`<option className="form-control" name="name" value={i.id} onChange={this.onChangeValue}>{i.name}</option>`

and you know the <open> will never changes.

Answer (score 1):

You are using **this.state.json.map**, it means **this.state.json** is an array. That's why you cannot use **this.state.json.id** because id doesn't exist. If there is at least 1 element and you want to access into your array, it will be **this.state.json[0].id** for the first element.

In your case, you want to get the value you set in **onChangeValue**.

```js
onChangeValue(e) {
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });
}
```

Based on your code, you can retrieve the selected id by using **this.state.name** because that's the name of your select input (name="name")

Comment: i dont have an input ! i have only a form and a <select > directy having an <option> , should this be the probleme ? because you said [[this.state.name because that's the name of your select input (name="name")]] , because i have a new probleme that s it : `app.js:66227 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined` .